# Flask-SocketIO blue print throwing error

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-sockets

I am trying to integrate Flask-SocketIO with my Flask application.

For some reason I am getting an import error that is triggered by the 
 ***from app import sockets;***
 that I have in my admin.py and I am not sure why.

I would greatly appreciate any help provided.

admin_online/admin.py

```
from flask_socketio import send, emit
from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room
from app import sockets;
#from ..  import sockets//error
# from ..app import socket //also an error
from flask import Blueprint


admin_online=Blueprint('admin_online', __name__)

@sockets.on('add-message', namespace='/')
def send_disconnect(message):
    print ',messae';
    emit('message', message)


@sockets.on('disconnect', namespace='/')
def test_disconnect():
    realoutput = "No"
    print  'dscone';


@sockets.on('join', namespace='/')
def on_join(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    print  'coonectg'+username;
    join_room(room)
    emit('message', username)


@sockets.on('leave', namespace='/')
def on_leave(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    leave_room(room)
    print  'leaving';
    emit('message', username)
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from mongo import init_mongo
from mail import init_flask_mail
from celery import Celery
from sockets import init_sockets
from admin_online import admin


def init_app():
    return Flask(__name__)


app = init_app()

# Celery configuration
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL'] = 'INFO'


def make_celery():
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask

    return celery

with app.app_context():
    init_flask_mail()
    init_mongo()
    sockets = init_sockets()



##imported here TOO  but not worked from admin_online import admin
app.register_blueprint(admin.admin_online)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    sockets.run(app, port=5000, debug=True)
```

socket.py

```
from flask import current_app as app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = None

def init_sockets():
  return SocketIO(app)
```

app structure

admin_online/admin.py

app.py

sockets.py

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
    from admin_online import admin
  File "E:\Iccacerate\ICaccerate-Backend\icarcerate-backend\admin_online\admin.py", line 3, in <module>

from app import sockets;

  File "E:\Ii\app.py", line 19, in <module>

    from admin_online import admin

ImportError: cannot import name admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have circular imports. The issue is as follows:

- `app.py` tries to import `admin` from `admin_online.py` (note that this is above the place in `app.py` where `sockets` is defined)
- `admin_online/admin.py` tries to import `sockets` from `app.py`, which does not exist yet, because the interpreter did not complete parsing of `app.py` yet.

One possible solution is to move the bit of code that initializes `sockets` in `app.py` above the `from admin_online import admin` line.